# Bootstrap Collapse table animation won't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm a beginner who is learning. I wanted to make simple project that I used bootstrap in it to make an expandable table but when I click the collapsible td it is only expanding and closing without any effect. I want to understand what conflict happens.

```js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/collapse.js";

const UserList = (props) => {

    return (
        <div >
            <table className="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Mail</th>
                        <th colSpan="3" scope="col">Contacts</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {props.users.map((user, i) => (

                        <Fragment>

                            <tr key={i} data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target={".multi-collapse" + i}
                                aria-controls={"multiCollapseExample" + i}  >
                                <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
                                <td>{user.name}</td>
                                <td>{user.mail}</td>
                                <td>{user.contact}</td>
                                <td><Link type="button"
                                    to={`edit/${user.id}`}
                                    className="btn btn-md btn-outline-primary"
                                >Edit</Link></td>
                                <td><button className="btn btn-md btn-outline-danger" data-target={i} onClick={(event) => props.deleteUserProp(user)}>Delete</button></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr className={"collapse multi-collapse" + i} id={"multiCollapseExample" + i} >
                                <td colSpan="6" className="collapsible clearfix" >
                                    <div className="coldiv" >  <h4> Address:</h4><p>{user.body}</p></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </Fragment>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
export default UserList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that the animation from bootstrap doesn't run on non block level elements like `<td>` or `<tr>`. It will show and hide it but the animation doesn't run because the way the animation works is dependent the element being `display: block`. So you COULD wrap the content inside the `<td>` element inside a `<div>` and then add the `collapse` class to that `<div>`.

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="element-id-to-identify-on-collapse-control" class="collapse">
            <p>This element would be hidden and the animation will run</p>
        </div>
    <td>
<tr>
```